# Частица «не» с причастиями

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия

Раздельно или слитно пишется "не" с причастием в данном случае?

**Пара несказанных слов.**

Answer (score 4):

**СКА́ЗАННЫЙ** (*прич. страд. прош. вр. от **сказать***)

*Сказанный*  — это *полное* причастие, а с полными причастиями частица "не" пишется слитно, если у этого причастия нет пояснительных слов.
[**НЕ с причастиями**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)

Например:
*А ведь буквально **пара сказанных** или **несказанных слов** могут изменить нашу судьбу.*
*Жизнь проходит, и все больше и больше накапливается **несказанных слов**, несделанных поступков*.

Если при полном причастии есть пояснительные слова, то частица "не" пишется раздельно.
Например:
*Пара **не сказанных**(кем?) **тобой** слов.*
*А ведь буквально **пара** сказанных или **не сказанных**(когда?) **вовремя** слов могут изменить нашу судьбу.*

[Не следует путать с *прилагательным **[несказа́нный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)***(1. *высок., трад.-поэт.* такой, который трудно выразить словами; неописуемый; 2. *перен., разг.* очень сильный; чрезвычайный).]